# async/await / assignments from function returns

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-5

Currently having a simple funtion :

```
async function getItem(id) {
  const item = await ... doing a bunch of time consuming stuff
  return item;
}
```

Coming from synchronous languages, and still understanding async/awaits from the surface; i'd expected the following to return the resolved item :

```
const item = getItem('items-8');
console.log(item); // Just getting a promise
```

The question is a bit 'cosmetic', but as async/await kind of solves callbacks, i'd be looking to get further and even avoid thenables things.

Is it possible to get such one-liner variable assignment with async/awaits ? What would be the syntax/code structure ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . It covers all sorts of things, including promises and async/await.

Comment: @estus If we stick to the titles of the main answer, we have The `"ES2017+:  Promises with async/await"` and `"ES2015+: Promises with then()"`. Let me be a but puzzled by the fact that the `ES2017` part ends up with `"then"`; it should then be advertised as `"ES2017+ with still a little bit of ES2015: Promises with async/await/THEN"`. This is more or less why i'm asking there, wondering if a one-liner pattern could be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async..await` is syntactic sugar for ES6 promises, it allows to write asynchronous code in synchrounous-like manner. The code that uses promises cannot be synchronous, because promises are asynchronous.

In order to be written in synchronous manner, the code that uses `getItem` should reside in `async` function, too. If it is top-level and doesn't reside in another function (like application initialization code), it can reside in `async` IIFE.

It's either

```
getItem('items-8').then(item => {
  ...
});
```

Or

```
// inside `async` function
const item = await getItem('items-8');
...
```

Comment: I start to get it, it can't happen outside the async right ? I was puzzled as, for example `async function returnValue(id) {  let item = await getItem(id); return item }); let it =  returnValue("items-8")` will still return a promise

Comment: Yes, it will return a promise indeed. And yes, we need to call `async` functions inside `async` functions in order to keep the code sync-like with no `then`s.